# Can form input write to a MySQL database and a PHP Session variable at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, post

Everything I'm doing is in Dreamweaver, PHP, and MySQL.  I'm trying to figure out how to allow a user to write to the database with a form and then use some of that information as a $_SESSION variable on the next page.  In this scenario, the user selects an option from a drop-down list and submits a form named "SelectBookForm" for a value 'play_system', writing a new row to my table 'characters', receiving a new "character_id" value.  "SelectBookForm" is also used to write a name to the field "character_name1".

```html
<?php require_once('Connections/DLP_RPG.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "SelectBookForm")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO characters (character_name1, play_system, character_owner) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['NewCharacterNameInput'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['CharacterOwner'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "character_new_book_select.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$login = mysql_query($query_login, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_login = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
$totalRows_login = mysql_num_rows($login);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_play_systems_recordset = "SELECT * FROM play_systems";
$play_systems_recordset = mysql_query($query_play_systems_recordset, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_play_systems_recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($play_systems_recordset);
$totalRows_play_systems_recordset = mysql_num_rows($play_systems_recordset);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_CharacterOwner = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.user_id = 
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = '{$_SESSION['MM_Username']}')";
$CharacterOwner = mysql_query($query_CharacterOwner, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_CharacterOwner = mysql_fetch_assoc($CharacterOwner);
$totalRows_CharacterOwner = mysql_num_rows($CharacterOwner);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" media="screen"/>
<title>Dark Ritual</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

 <div class="header">DLP RPG testing</div>

 <div class="main_right">

  <div class="padded">
   <h1>Help files</h1>
   <p>This would hopefully be where help files load when a user clicks on something.  Unobtrusive to people that know what they what to enter, but helpful to people that like to poke around.</p>
   
  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="subnav">

  <h1>Character Sheets</h1>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="character_list.php">My Characters</a></li>
            <li><a href="character_new_system_select.php">New Character</a></li>
  </ul><br>
   <ul><li><a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Logout</a></li></ul>
            <h1>Do you want to help?</h1>
            <li><a href="http://dangerouslylow.com/?page_id=6">Contact page</a></li>
            
  </ul>

  </div>
  
 <div class="main">

  <div class="padded">

   <h1>Select a play system</h1>
<p class="meta">Every system is different and how you interact with the site will be radically different depending on what you choose.  You're making a new character, so the first question is, What game do you want to play?</p>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="SelectBookForm" method="POST" id="SelectBookForm"> 
  <select name="select" size="1" form="SelectBookForm">
    <?php
do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_play_systems_recordset['play_system']?>"><?php echo $row_play_systems_recordset['play_system']?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_play_systems_recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($play_systems_recordset));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($play_systems_recordset);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($play_systems_recordset, 0);
   $row_play_systems_recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($play_systems_recordset);
  }
?>
  </select>
  <input name="CharacterOwner" type="hidden" id="CharacterOwner" value="<?php echo $row_CharacterOwner['user_id']; ?>"><input name="NewCharacterNameInput" type="text" required id="NewCharacterNameInput" form="SelectBookForm" placeholder="Give your character a name!" size="25" maxlength="128">
      <BR>
  <input name="NewCharacterSubmit" type="submit" id="NewCharacterSubmit" form="SelectBookForm" value="Select system and start my character">
      
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="PlaySystemForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="SelectBookForm">
</form>
<br>
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="175"><h2>System Name:</h2></td>
      <td width="175"><h2>Manufacturer:</h2></td>
    </tr></tbody>
<?php do { ?>
  <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="175"><?php echo $row_play_systems_recordset['play_system']; ?></td>
        <td width="175"><a href="<?php echo $row_play_systems_recordset['play_system_url']; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="img/<?php echo $row_play_systems_recordset['play_system_graphic_filename']; ?>" alt="" width="150" border="0"/></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <?php } while ($row_play_systems_recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($play_systems_recordset)); ?>
<p>Ideally this would be a dynamic list based on products that are out of testing and available.  If you're a system creator or whatever kind of site admin, they should be able to see everything.  Still trying to figure out how to make it load dynamically.  Maybe write to a cookie so it holds in POST the system selection?</p>
            <p>Next you'll choose what books you want to start with</p>

...  </div>

 </div>
 
 <div class="clearer"><span></span></div>

 <div class="footer">
  
  <span class="left">Most of what is behind this page is copyrighted and used without permission</span>
  
  <span class="right">Design by <a href="http://arcsin.se/">Arcsin</a> <a href="http://templates.arcsin.se/">Web Templates</a></span>
  
  <div class="clearer"><span></span></div>

 </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($login);

mysql_free_result($play_systems_recordset);
?>
```

What I would like to do is take the 'character_id' value for the new row that was created and the 'play_system' value that was written in as $_SESSION values.  I'm expecting there to be a lot of values and rows and the next page is going to have another drop-down list that I'm hoping will be restricted by the selection in the first page.  With a little help I think passing more SESSION values will let me get to the end of the process I'm trying to start.

This is the code on the second page:

```html
<?php require_once('Connections/DLP_RPG.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);
 
  $logoutGoTo = "pretty_index.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "index.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$login = mysql_query($query_login, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_login = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
$totalRows_login = mysql_num_rows($login);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_BooksRecordset = "SELECT * FROM character_system";
$BooksRecordset = mysql_query($query_BooksRecordset, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_BooksRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($BooksRecordset);
$totalRows_BooksRecordset = mysql_num_rows($BooksRecordset);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" media="screen"/>
<title>Dark Ritual</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

 <div class="header">DLP RPG testing</div>

 <div class="main_right">

  <div class="padded">
   <h1>Help files</h1>
   <p>This would hopefully be where help files load when a user clicks on something.  Unobtrusive to people that know what they what to enter, but helpful to people that like to poke around.</p>
   
  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="subnav">

  <h1>Character Sheets</h1>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="character_list.php">My Characters</a></li>
            <li><a href="character_new_system_select.php">New Character</a></li>
  </ul><br>
   <ul><li><a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Logout</a></li></ul>
            <h1>Do you want to help?</h1>
            <li><a href="http://dangerouslylow.com/?page_id=6">Contact page</a></li>
            
  </ul>

  </div>
  
 <div class="main">

  <div class="padded">
<h1>Which campaigns and books do you want to start with?</h1>
<p>If you're just starting a new character and not all that familiar with the campaigns available, I would suggest only picking one book.  If you know you want a very specific type of character, then feel free to select as many as you want.  Don't forget to include the base books in your selection!</p>

<form method="post" id="BookSelectionForm">
<select name="BookSelections" size="10" multiple id="BookSelections" form="BookSelectionForm">
  <?php
do {  
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_BooksRecordset['character_system_id']?>"><?php echo $row_BooksRecordset['book']?></option>
  <?php
} while ($row_BooksRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($BooksRecordset));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($BooksRecordset);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($BooksRecordset, 0);
   $row_BooksRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($BooksRecordset);
  }
?>
</select>
</form>

   <h1>Select which books to use</h1>
   <p class="meta">The 'book' table has a 'play_system' field that is equal to the text of the name of the system. The intention here is to only show the books for the system and not confuse the user.</p>
            
           <p>If the post data shows it would ideally be only for the play_system values</p>
           
<?php
echo "this is the _POST data";
print_r($_POST);
//or
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    echo $key.'='.$value.'<br />';
?><BR>
<?php
echo "this is the _SESSION data";
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>
  </div>

 </div>
 
 <div class="clearer"><span></span></div>

 <div class="footer">
  
  <span class="left">Most of what is behind this page is copyrighted and used without permission</span>
  
  <span class="right">Design by <a href="http://arcsin.se/">Arcsin</a> <a href="http://templates.arcsin.se/">Web Templates</a></span>
  
  <div class="clearer"><span></span></div>

 </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($login);

mysql_free_result($BooksRecordset);
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/DLP_RPG.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);
 
  $logoutGoTo = "pretty_index.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "index.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$login = mysql_query($query_login, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_login = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
$totalRows_login = mysql_num_rows($login);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_BooksRecordset = "SELECT * FROM character_system";
$BooksRecordset = mysql_query($query_BooksRecordset, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_BooksRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($BooksRecordset);
$totalRows_BooksRecordset = mysql_num_rows($BooksRecordset);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" media="screen"/>
<title>Dark Ritual</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

 <div class="header">DLP RPG testing</div>

 <div class="main_right">

  <div class="padded">
   <h1>Help files</h1>
   <p>This would hopefully be where help files load when a user clicks on something.  Unobtrusive to people that know what they what to enter, but helpful to people that like to poke around.</p>
   
  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="subnav">

  <h1>Character Sheets</h1>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="character_list.php">My Characters</a></li>
            <li><a href="character_new_system_select.php">New Character</a></li>
  </ul><br>
   <ul><li><a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Logout</a></li></ul>
            <h1>Do you want to help?</h1>
            <li><a href="http://dangerouslylow.com/?page_id=6">Contact page</a></li>
            
  </ul>

  </div>
  
 <div class="main">

  <div class="padded">
<h1>Which campaigns and books do you want to start with?</h1>
<p>If you're just starting a new character and not all that familiar with the campaigns available, I would suggest only picking one book.  If you know you want a very specific type of character, then feel free to select as many as you want.  Don't forget to include the base books in your selection!</p>

<form method="post" id="BookSelectionForm">
<select name="BookSelections" size="10" multiple id="BookSelections" form="BookSelectionForm">
  <?php
do {  
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_BooksRecordset['character_system_id']?>"><?php echo $row_BooksRecordset['book']?></option>
  <?php
} while ($row_BooksRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($BooksRecordset));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($BooksRecordset);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($BooksRecordset, 0);
   $row_BooksRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($BooksRecordset);
  }
?>
</select>
</form>

   <h1>Select which books to use</h1>
   <p class="meta">The 'book' table has a 'play_system' field that is equal to the text of the name of the system. The intention here is to only show the books for the system and not confuse the user.</p>
            
           <p>If the post data shows it would ideally be only for the play_system values</p>
           
<?php
echo "this is the _POST data";
print_r($_POST);
//or
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    echo $key.'='.$value.'<br />';
?><BR>
<?php
echo "this is the _SESSION data";
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>
  </div>

 </div>
 
 <div class="clearer"><span></span></div>

 <div class="footer">
  
  <span class="left">Most of what is behind this page is copyrighted and used without permission</span>
  
  <span class="right">Design by <a href="http://arcsin.se/">Arcsin</a> <a href="http://templates.arcsin.se/">Web Templates</a></span>
  
  <div class="clearer"><span></span></div>

 </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($login);

mysql_free_result($BooksRecordset);
?>
```

I'm still trying to figure out which section of the code runs when the button is pressed.

I think it's here:

```html
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "SelectBookForm")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO characters (character_name1, play_system, character_owner) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['NewCharacterNameInput'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['CharacterOwner'], "int"));
        $_SESSION['play_system'] = clone GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "text");
        $_SESSION['character_owner'] = clone GetSQLValueString($_POST['CharacterOwner'], "int"));
        $_SESSION['character_name1'] = clone GetSQLValueString($_POST['NewCharacterNameInput'], "text");

  mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "character_new_book_select.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

So I tried to create the session variables, the line for CharacterOwner keeps coming up as an issue though.  Dreamweaver flags it as a problem, but the syntax is the same so I'm confused as to what is causing the issue.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/.../character_new_system_select.php on line 118

I'll try to figure out where the extra parenthesis is or is missing from

Comment: So I guess the next questions are "how to tie pressing the 'Submit' button to both actions?" and "do all of the session variables need to be created before the button is pushed or will it make a new one?"

Comment: Well, after (or before, but within the same request) saving to the database, update the appropriate session state. If that "doesn't work" or "isn't working" then you'll need to find out *what part in particular* doesn't work as intended - and explain it [simply].

Answer (score -1):

So my edit worked after I removed the "clone" method.  The second page correctly has the session variables.  Fingers are crossed that I can figure out the syntax to make it do what I want.  I feel a little like the aliens in the Tommyknockers, able to make the machine do something useful, but with no idea how it does it.  Thanks!